# im using xpath and cant interact with the textbox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[Screenshot from inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpz8A.png)

The absolute XPath is working but I'm trying to use a relative XPath since it's the best practice.

here is the xpath im using:

> 

//*[@id=":r2i:"][@class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-1o6z5ng"][@type="text"]

> 

I'm getting this error every time

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Share the relative XPath which you have tried and which is giving you the exception.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: im using this xpath

//*[@id=":r2i:"][@class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-1o6z5ng"][@type="text"]

Comment: maybe try with //input[@id=':r22:']

Comment: same result when i use //input[@id=':r22:']

Comment: be sure to use a proper, explicit webdriverwait: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/  If this does not help, you need to include the page's markup.  (right-click, choose "inspect", copy/paste into your post